# Django Calculations within Model.py don't update without a Server Reset

Tags: python, django, caching, model

I have a few calculations within my Models file.

The premise of this is that I have a 'rate' which is updated on a weekly basis, and this has an impact upon 2/3 columns within my eventual HTML table.

I bring forward the latest rate as such:

```
class Hedge_rate(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Hedge_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.Hedge_rate)

V = Hedge_rate.objects.all().first()
latest_rate = V.Hedge_rate
```

Then, my primary calculations are as follows:

```
@property
def spot_amount(self):
    return self.usd_amount/latest_rate
```

The problem I am facing is that, let's say the "latest rate" is current "2" - If I then update this figure to "5", the numbers within the calculation (as well as if I 'print' Latest Rate') will remain as if the Latest rate is still 2. It only updates to 5 upon a server reset.

I suspect this is some sort of Caching issue? Is there a way I can trigger a cache 'wipe' upon each form submission when updating the rate?

What is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the latest rate in the function, so:

```
@property
def spot_amount(self):
    latest = Hedge_rate.objects.first()
    return self.usd_amount/latest.Hedge_rate
```

otherwise Django will make a single query when loading the file where you calculate the latest rate, and simply never change that, regardless whether a new `Hedge_rate` object is created, or the latest `Hedge_rate` is removed or updated.

Comment: Thank you - This worked!

It seems so logical, but the reason I avoided even trying it was because my PyCharm app wasn't bringing 'Hedge_rate' up as an option after 'latest.' in my attempt, so thought that it wouldn't work.

Seems like this is a case of trusting the technology more than my brain

Comment: @OperGo: PyCharm professional has support for Django, but PyCharm itself can not really reason about Django since the amount of logic of the meta-classes is too inaccessible for the IDE to make sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a caching issue. The query `Hedge_rate.objects.all().first()` only executes once when the server starts or restarts but when the value gets updated in the database, the query will not run again. Instead, get the latest value from the database while calculating the amount.